# Is there a way to manage a global store in flutter?

Tags: flutter, store

In an app we may want to display some pages depend on some conditions like is authenticated or not. So managing a store is better in my view. Is there a way to manage a global store in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a static class having all parameters eg.

```
class AppConstants {
  static String dbName="Documents/APPDBv1.1.db";
  static String userid="[USER_ID]";
  static String token="[TOKEN]";
  static bool authenticated=false;
  static String syncDate="01/01/2019 00:00";

  static final List<String> myValue= ["A","B","C","D"];

}
```

the specific parameters can be saved to database/shared preference/local storage and can be retrieved from database/shared preference/local storage and stored in this static class.